# CART algorithm of matlab 'fitctree' takes account on the attributes order why ?

Tags: matlab, tree, classification, cart, decision-tree

here is an example mentionning that fitctree of matlab takes into account the features order ! why ?

```
load ionosphere % Contains X and Y variables
Mdl = fitctree(X,Y)
view(Mdl,'mode','graph');
X1=fliplr(X);
Mdl1 = fitctree(X1,Y)
view(Mdl1,'mode','graph');
```

Not the same model, thus not the same classification accuracy despite dealing with the same features ?

Comment: It's not about reordering  while changing the label. X represent a matrix of features and Y a comlumn vector of class label. 
Here is a simple example:Suppose that we have 2 kind a people Conspicuous and greedy person the first will be happy if he get 5 apples and 3 bananas or  2 apples and 2 bananas, the other will not if he get 10 apples and 9 bananas or 8 apples and 8 bananas as he is greedy. In this case: training matrix X will be '[5 3 ; 2 2 ; 10 9; 8 8] and the Y will be [happy happy angry  angry]'. Normaly,if we permute our feature i.e [5 2 10 8]' and [3 2 9 8 ] we get the same model

Comment: When I run your code, I get fairly similar trees, with very very minor differences. I assume the only differences are because to divide class A=[2 1 2 1] and class B=[5 6 5 6 ] you can divide anywhere between (2-5) and the classification would be perfect. The numerical solver falls somewhere in the middle, and classifies  correctly, thus stops.

Comment: Even it classifies correctly, normaly it should present the same model as the feature's order does not matter. if [2 1 2 1 ; 5 6 5 6 ] is the training matrix of Y=[A B]' thus the model should be the same if we use [1 1 2 2 ; 6 6 5 5 ] for the same Y, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `X`contains 34 predictors. The predictors contain no names and `fitctree`just refers to them by their column numbers `x1, x2, ..., x34`. If you flip the table, the column number changes and therefore their name. So `x1 -> x34`. `x2 -> x33`, etc..

In for most nodes this does not matter because CART always divides a node by the predictor that maximises the impurity gain between the two child nodes. But sometimes there are multiple predictors which result in the same impurity gain. Then it just picks the one with the lowest column number. And since the column number changed by reordering the predictors, you end up with a different predictor at that node.

E.g. let's look at the marked split:

**Original order (`mdl`):** 
[image: noflip]
**Flipped order (`mdl1`):**
[image: flip]

Up to this point always the same predictor and values have been chosen. Names changed due to order, e.g. `x5` in the old data = `x30` in the new model. But `x3` and `x6` are actually different predictors. `x6` in the flipped order is `x29` in the original order.

A scatter plot between those predictors shows how this could happen:

[image: complot]

Where blue and cyan lines mark the splits performed by `mdl` and `mdl1` respectively at that node. As we can see, both splits yield child nodes with the same number of elements per label! Therefore CART can chose any of the two predictors, it will cause the same impurity gain.

In that case it seems to just pick the one with the lower column number. In the non-flipped table `x3` is chosen instead of `x29` because `3 < 29`. But if you flip the tables, `x3` becomes `x32` and `x29` becomes `x6`. Since `6 < 32` you now end up with `x6`, the original `x29`.

Ultimately this does not matter - the decision tree of the flipped table is not better or worse. It only happens in the lower nodes where the tree starts to overfit. So you really don't have to care about it.

**Appendix:**

Code for scatter plot generation:

```
load ionosphere % Contains X and Y variables
Mdl = fitctree(X,Y);
view(Mdl,'mode','graph');
X1=fliplr(X);
Mdl1 = fitctree(X1,Y);
view(Mdl1,'mode','graph');

idx = (X(:,5)>=0.23154 & X(:,27)>=0.999945 & X(:,1)>=0.5);
remainder = X(idx,:);
labels = cell2mat(Y(idx,:));

gscatter(remainder(:,3), remainder(:,(35-6)), labels,'rgb','osd');

limits = [-1.5 1.5];
xlim(limits)
ylim(limits)
xlabel('predictor 3')
ylabel('predictor 29')
hold on
plot([0.73 0.73], limits, '-b')
plot(limits, [0.693 0.693], '-c')
legend({'b' 'g'})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. But why decision tree does not take account on the same predictors to built the tree even if we reorder them, even if  " multiple predictors will result in the same impurity gain " ?

Comment: @LMarwa I expanded the explanation. Is it now clear?